# using multiple meta_key and meta_value in query_posts

Tags: custom-field, query-posts, post-meta

how can i use multiple meta_key and meta_value in query_posts?

For example, I want to find multiple content with two different meta_key and meta_value. How do I do this?

i using this code but not effective:

```
query_posts('meta_key=test2&meta_value=hello&meta_key=test2&meta_value=bye');
```

please help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently possible with query arguments alone (realm of filtering raw SQL query and such).

If your task is not time-critical then I suggest to wait for upcoming WP 3.1 release. It will feature much more flexible querying capabilities for custom fields.

See [Advanced Metadata Queries](http://scribu.net/wordpress/advanced-metadata-queries.html) for post on upcoming improvements.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $args = array(
        'post_type'         =>  'custompost_type',
        'posts_per_page'    =>  '1',
        'meta_query'        =>  array(
                'relations' =>  'AND', // you can use OR also as your requirement
            array(
                    'key'   =>  'serial-number',
                    'value' =>  '123'
            ),
            array(
                    'key'   =>  'model-number',
                    'value' =>  '456'
            ),
        ),
        'post_status'       =>  'publish',
    );
    $posts = get_posts($args);

if(sizeof($posts) > 0){
  var_dump($posts);
}
```